# Como tirar barra de rolamento horizontal do meu site?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*-------Conf.CSS--------*/
body{
    background-color:#FFF; 
}

header{
 background-color:#222;
 width:100%;
 height:78px;
 float:left;
}

.logo{
    width:10.9375%;
 height:66px;
 float:left;
 margin-left:162px;
 margin-top:9px;
}

/*-------Menu--------*/

.nav{
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
 background-color:#4682B4;    
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:1.000em;
 color:#fff;
    float:left;
}

.menu{
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
 margin-left:11.23046875%;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    min-width: 200px;
 z-index:99;
}

.nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav ul li a, visited{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.813em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
 background-color: #222;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

.img-menu{
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="logo">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width="112" height="60" alt="Meu site" title="Meu site"/></a>
   </div>
</header>

<div class="nav">
 <div class="img-menu"><img src="img/icn-menu.png"/></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Gameplays</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trailers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Imagens</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Áudio e Vídeo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Segurança</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sistemas Oprecionais</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Os Mais Baixados</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Android</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">IOS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li> <a href="#">Internet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Redes Socias</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Diversão</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Filmes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animes/desenhos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Memes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Histórias bisarras</a>
                    </li>
             </ul>
                <li> <a href="#">TI</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Progamção</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorias</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

Está acontecendo um erro no menu do meu site que faz o site ficar com barra de rolamento horizontal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste seu código (css + html), provavelmente você possui algum elemento que está ultrapassando os limites.

Comment: @Randrade vou colocar !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, isso esta acontecendo pois voce tem uma div com largura de 100%, e com margem de 11% totalizando 111%, coloca uma div dentro da div do menu com a margem.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta adicionar isso ao seu CSS:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```